# Access instance variable inside anonymous callback PHP

Tags: php

Lets suppose i have a class & i have to set instance variable from inside the callback.

```
class A{
   protected $user;

   public __construct(){
      /* Some function here which accept callback */
      StoreData(['name'=>'Stackoverflow'],function($response){
           //how to assign value to $user here???
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Use the `use` keyword. http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: use ( ?) , ?  would be $user or  $this->user

Comment: when i write , use($user)  it gives me error "variable undefined", and when i use , use($this->user) , its gives "Cannot use $this as lexical variable"

Comment: What are you trying to do inside that call back function, you may not need the entire user object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the entire object to a variable and inject it into the `use()` thereby modifying the object *(presumably this is what you mean?)*:

```
<?php
class bug
    {
        protected $user;

        public  function test()
            {
                $thisObj    =   $this;
                goo('test',function() use ($thisObj) {
                    $thisObj->user  =   'foooooooo';
                });

                echo $this->user;
            }
    }

function goo($val,$callback)
    {
        $callback();
    }

$bug    =   new bug();
$bug->test();
```

You will get:

```
foooooooo
```

Comment: Done !!!!!!!!! why i forgot that ,,, $this can be used as object to pass in use()  , Thanks <3

Comment: lol. What's funny, is I have injected the entire object before using this method, but I was unsure before testing that it would modify the original object...so I learned something new myself!

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
class A{
    protected $user;

    public function  __construct(){
        $this->user = 'hehexd';
    }

    public function  getFunction(){
        $temp = $this->user; // or a reference
        $rval = function($response) use ($temp){
            echo $temp;
        };

        return $rval;
    }
}

$a = new A();
$func = $a->getFunction();
$func('response');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = 'hello';

// No "use"
$example = function () {
    var_dump($message);
};
$example();

// Inherit $message
$example = function () use ($message) {
    var_dump($message);
};
$example();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php